# How can I combine images into one container in Docker (as IIB is dependent on MQ)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I am new to docker, and as I am trying to configure an IBM integration environment using docker. I have used docker pull command to install two different images, one is the IBM Integration Bus (IIB) and the other is IBM Message Queueing (MQ). Then I ran each of the images in separate containers using docker run command.

The problem is, IIB is depending on MQ for its broker creation. I created the queue manager in the MQ container, and then created a broker in the iib container. I need a way to link the broker contianer with queue manager container, or combine them if possible.

https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-connect-to-queue-manager/#docker

https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/iib/

Can someone help and provide instructions?

Comment: You probably do not want to combine them. You need to run them so that they can see each other. Most containers that provide a service, have documentation as to what port they run on and usually provide example as to how to connect to them from another container. See also: docker-compose

Comment: Just as DannyB said, it will be better to use docker-compose, and I have found [this example on github](https://github.com/denseidel/ibm-integration-bus-docker-bestpractice) that you might try or get inspiration from it in order to connect your containers together

Comment: You don't state what version of IIB you are using, but at IIB 10 you no longer need a local queue manager.  You can use roles to grant broker permissions and you can connect to the queue manager if you need to send or receive messages via a MQ client connection.  If you are relying on broker looking at queue manager permissions based on `SYSTEM.BROKER.AUTH*` queues then likely you do need a local broker since I believe this functionality still has to be done in binding mode using ipcs resources local on the same server as the queue manager.

Comment: You can't combine them, you need to run them together with `docker-compose`. Here is a good tutorial https://docker-curriculum.com/#multi-container-environments

Comment: @AliBahrami The example is based on TCP/IP communication. The requirement for a local queue manager for IIB to connect to requires IIB to communicate to the queue manger via shared memory and semaphores, is that supported across two containers?

Comment: If you can work with the latest IIB version, now called ACE, look at these [images](https://github.com/ot4i/ace-docker).

Comment: @DanielSteinmann sounds like an answer to me :)

Comment: @JoshMc ok, I will do :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you can work with the latest IIB version, now called ACE, look at these [images](https://github.com/ot4i/ace-docker).